# How can [String: AnyObject] be an AnyObject, but [String: AnyObject?] can't?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This code will (in Swift 1.2) fail on the last line:

```
import Foundation

let dictionary1 = [String: AnyObject]()
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dictionary1, forKey: "test1")

let dictionary2 = [String: AnyObject?]()
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dictionary2, forKey: "test2")
```

(The `setObject` method takes `AnyObject` as its first argument.)

Normally, Swift would fail on the first line, but due to some magic when importing Foundation, all built-in types generally become implementors of `AnyObject` (presumably because they will be bridged as `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc. under the hood). I am depending on this behavior to be able to pass Swift data into the `NSUserDefaults`.

My problem is that I want to pass in a dictionary where values may be `nil`, but for some reason that doesn't work despite importing Foundation. Is there a way to work around this without using NS* types in my Swift code?

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried calling `dictionary2._bridgeToObjectiveC()` which throws `EXC_I386_INVOP`. I guess I'll need to do a manual entry by entry conversion to `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can not convert a dictionary with optional to NSDictionary. As a workaround you can Use a [String : AnyObject] and set it to [NSNull](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/)

The NSNull class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects (which don’t allow nil values).

Comment: I'm getting the same error for `dictionary2` using `setValue`. The signature of `setValue` has `AnyObject?` instead of `AnyObject`, which doesn't help since Swift is saying that `dictionary2` doesn't even conform to `AnyObject`.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry for that. Looks like you can not convert a dictionary with optional to NSDictionary. As a workaround you can Use a [String : AnyObject] and set it to NSNull (The NSNull class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects (which don’t allow nil values). I'll update my answer.